# IIS Express path to applicationhost.config in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, iis-express

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2010 what value to use for the /config parameter when IIS Express is started?

Using Process Explorer I can see:

- the iisexpress.exe process is started by Visual Studio with the /config parameter pointing to '**My Documents\IISExpress**' via the environment variable named `IIS_USER_HOME` .

However I need to store my applicationhost.config in another location.
Changing that `IIS_USER_HOME` variable might do the trick (?) but I don't know any way to access it.

#### What I have tried:

I guess that these instructions on [how to debug .NET web projects with IIS Express pre SP1](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/7/11/debug-your-net-web-project-with-iis-express-t.aspx) might work for me but they seems like a hassle to follow. There ought to be an easier way?

This StackOverflow question about [global variables within IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845970/global-variables-within-iis-express) suggest that I should move the location of 'My Documents'. Unfortunately that is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change IIS_USER_HOME because this is set by IISExpress.exe during the process startup.

I am not sure about concerns you have about [how to debug .NET web projects with IIS Express pre SP1](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/7/11/debug-your-net-web-project-with-iis-express-t.aspx) .

If you don't want to use macros in VS, probably you can just start IIS Express from command line with /config switch and then from visual Studio attach to iisexpress.exe and debug your web application.