# IISExpress - redirection.config cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, onedrive, iis-express, azure-devtest-labs

I have a virtual machine created from the Azure DevTest Lab environment. I CYOD this virtual machine, so I have onedrive business and all security restrictions of company.

I just tested all the solutions of lack of permission on the IISExpress folder and his items but nothing worked.

> **I notice that all files under Documents are owned to the company "File Owenership" column and no way to change ownership to personal**

- Documents\IISExpress\config\ **applicationhost.config**
- Documents\IISExpress\config\ **aspnet.config**
- Documents\IISExpress\config\ **redirection.config**

[image]

The problem is with the CYOD and onedrive. File ownership is restricting this operation but I don't know how I can change that.

[image]

### Diagnose with Process Monitor:

[image]

This process is denied. Entering in the event properties in the tab of "Process" the user has full control on the entire Documents folder, so I don't know how is denied this access. --> **Update: file ownership is restricting the access.**

[image]

### Changing location of IISExpress

Very good answer if someone will change the IISExpress location: 
[How do I prevent IISExpress & My Web Sites folders from cluttering up my My Documents folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896911/how-do-i-prevent-iisexpress-my-web-sites-folders-from-cluttering-up-my-my-docu/17590827#17590827)

Comment: It is interesting that VS2017/2019 does not even use that folder any more, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-solution-file What kind of project are you working on? You might run some diagnostics to learn more of its settings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: Please try to diagnose permission issue with process monitor.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon. You could add a filter like "result= access denied" and it should tell us where and  what permission are required.

Comment: @JokiesDing I just added the Process Monitor result of access denied items from devenv.exe

Comment: @soydachis. Please double click the create file line and it will show who is the application user and what permission are required.

Comment: @JokiesDing in this event properties in the tab "Process" the user has full control in the entire Documents Folder

Comment: Think I know why it's not working. The file ownership is assigned to the company and it's not possible to change it. @JokiesDing

Comment: @soydachi I'm not familiar with onedrive. Is it possible to install IIS EXPRESS under local user instead of onedrive profile?

Comment: @JokiesDing I changed IIS Express location but after that I have this issue in VS2017: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520084/visual-studio-doesnt-recognize-iis-express-customu.html

Comment: If you're running windows with VS & IISExpress as a vmware guest and sharing you're Host's Documents folder with the VM you may get this error. Solution is to unshare the host Documents folder with the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matty-j answer fixed mines: [How do I prevent IISExpress & My Web Sites folders from cluttering up my My Documents folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896911/how-do-i-prevent-iisexpress-my-web-sites-folders-from-cluttering-up-my-my-docu/17590827#17590827)

Anyway, VS2017 installs IIS Express, which is what is causing these folders to be created. I have found two solutions for dealing with the unwanted folders.

1. Uninstall IIS Express. You can do this from the normal Windows 'Uninstall a Program' part of Control Panel.
2. Change the folder location that IIS Express uses, as follows. Be warned: anyone doing this risks causing problems with their computer if you don't know what you are doing, so you do so at your own risk. Please make appropriate backups along the way as well too!

   a) Close Visual Studio.

   b) Create a new folder fo   r the IIS Express sub-folders:

   eg. `D:\My Documents\Data\Microsoft\IISExpress`

   c) Move the existing unwanted IISExpress subfolders (`config, Logs, TraceLogFiles`) from your `My Documents > IISExpress` folder to the folder created in step b).

   d) Create a new folder for the `My Web Sites` folder, I suggest also under the folder created in step b).

   eg. `D:\My Documents\Data\Microsoft\IISExpress\Websites`

   Under this folder, create a website for the default IIS Express website (in case it "auto-magically" reappears it's ugly head again later on).

   eg. `D:\My Documents\Data\Microsoft\IISExpress\Websites\Default`

   e) Go to the newly located config folder at:

   eg. `D:\My Documents\Data\Microsoft\IISExpress\config, and:`

   i. Open the file `applicationhost.config` in your text editor (eg. Notepad).

   ii. Find the node `sites > site > application path > virtualDirectory path` for WebSite1, and change the physicalPath value from `%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1` to the IIS Express default website folder you created in step d).

   Eg. `%IIS_SITES_HOME%\Websites\Default.`

   Note that `%IIS_SITES_HOME%` points to your 'Documents' folder (this appears to be a "feature" of IIS Express, I can't find a way to change it, and it appears to be auto-configured when IIS Express starts up, which it does by using the `applicationhost.config` file).

   Do the same for any other sites created by IIS Express.

   f) Create a new registry entry pointing IIS Express to the new folders you created (partly explained by MS here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme). FYI the registry key doesn't previously exist, as IIS Express uses a default of my `Documents` unless this key exists:

   i. Open the Windows 'Run' box, eg. `(Windows Key) + R`

   ii. Type `regedit`

   iii. Navigate to key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft`

   iv. *Right click* the `Microsoft` key (that you have just navigated to), and choose: `New > Key`

   v. Type `IISExpress`

   vi. *Right click* the `IISExpress` key that you have just created, and choose: `New > String Value`

   vii. Type `CustomUserHome`, and hit the `Enter` key to save it.

   viii. Double-click the `CustomUserHome` string to enter a value for it, and for the `Value Data:` field, type in the path to the new IIS Express folder you created in step b), for example: `D:\My Documents\Data\Microsoft\IISExpress`. Press OK, and you can now close the Registry Editor.

   g) Reopen Visual Studio, and it should start using the new folders, as well as not create the folders in your `Documents` folder anymore. Yay!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Solution for me was to go to
[Documents]
Then right click [IISExpress] folder
Then chick (Always keep on this device)

[image: check (Always keep on this device)]

OneDrive was making the issue.